# Accessing local storage using PouchDB from within iframe in firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe, indexeddb, pouchdb

I am using pouchDB and I am trying to access local storage (same origin) from within cross domain iframe 
This is working fine in chrome but not in firefox.

to clarify : I am on "foobar.com" , and I loaded an iframe containing my html having origin "test.com" and this html is trying to access its own local storage i.e having same origin "test.com".

Just to show an example, I served this HTML from my server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test page</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pouchdb-5.1.0.min.js"></script>
<body>    
    <button id="create">create db</button>
    <button id="read">read records</button>
</body>

<script>
       document.getElementById('create').addEventListener('click', createDB, false);
       document.getElementById('read').addEventListener('click', readDB, false);

       function createDB(){
              db = new PouchDB('noobDB');
              console.log(db.adapter);
       }

       function readDB(){
              db = new PouchDB('noobDB');
              db.allDocs({include_docs : true})
                .then(function(result){console.log(result)})
                .catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
       }
</script>
```

In firefox; when i load this html in main browser window and create and retrieve records every thing works fine, but when I load this html page in an iframe and tries to read records, it does not work.

But in chrome when I load this HTML in an iframe and read records, it works fine.

what is the cause of not reading records (as well as other operations related to local DB) from within an iframe in firefox

Comment: Are you using webSQL or IndexDB?  Adapters say that webSQL will only work in chrome and safari: http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html

Comment: yeah i am using indexedDB because websql is unavailable in Firefox for pouchDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue from firefox where it was unable to access indexedDB from iframe.
This issue has been resolved in the latest version of mozilla firefox i.e **v43.0.4**